# Networkcableanalyser RJ45

Tags: cable, test-equipment

I am searching for a networkcable analyser for CAT5e to CAT6 STP cables, 100Mbit/s and 1Gbit/s speeds.
We are making the connectors ourselfes and it comes to problems from time to time and I need an analyser which can measure Q (and other important parameters) where I just have to plug in the RJ45 connectors. The two ends are about 10 meters apart from each other. Plus points for a batterie operated device, but it's not a must have.
Up until now, I made the measurement with wireshark and a stress test and had a look for retransmission and so on, but I am not interested in a post problem analysis.

Answer (score 1):

## Fluke/NetAlly - $400 - $3000

Fluke's units are considered the gold standard, particularly the LinkRunner, LinkSprinter, and CableIQ. However, they're also extremely expensive, with prices ranging from ~$400 for the LinkSprinter 300 to ~$3000 for the LinkRunner G2. Used units are also a good option if you don't want to pay quite the price; their solid construction means buying used is a perfectly good option.

## Pocketethernet - $180

If you don't want to drop quite that much cash, the Pocketethernet is a solid unit that, when connected to a phone, provides much the same features for €167.23. Their app isn't the most polished, but hey, even the pricy units aren't too pretty, and it works quite well.

## NF-308 - $40

If you really don't want to spend too much money, FS offers a basic unit that can do the job, as long as you don't need to much from it. For some reason, a rebrand of the same unit appears to be offered by Monoprice for slightly less than FS sells it, as the "Monoprice Professional Coaxial, RJ-45, RJ-11/12, BNC, and USB Multifunction Tester with LCD Display".

Comment: Ok, I just had a look at the Pocketethernet device and I see TDR and BER measurement. From what I've seen in my measurements is that TDR (At least the inbuild TDR of D-Link DGS1510 switches) is not enough to see the error if, for example a cable is not fully connected in the RJ45 connector. Have you made any experience with this device? 
Currently I see the Fluke DSX devices for 7000 and more.
Any experience with the IDEAL LanTek III?

Comment: Unfortunately not, this is based of the advice of my friends and the networking community.